# Count overlapping substring in a string

Tags: python

Say I have `string = 'hannahannahskdjhannahannah'` and I want to count the number of times the string `hannah` occurs, I can't simply use `count`, because that only counts the substring once in each case. That is, I am expecting to return `4` but only returns `2` when I run this with `string.count('hannah')`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a running index to fetch the next occurance:

```
bla = 'hannahannahskdjhannahannah'
cnt = 0
idx = 0
while True:
    idx = bla.find('hannah', idx)
    if idx >= 0:
        cnt += 1
        idx += 1
    else:
        break
print(cnt)
```

Gives:

```
>> 4
```

Comment: This is perfect Ricky! Thank you very much for your help. Is there any more specific documentation around running index approach?

Comment: Not that I know of. Just common sense.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
>>> d = {}
>>> string = 'hannahannahskdjhannahannah'
>>> for i in xrange(0,len(string)-len('hannah')+1):
...     if string[i:i+len('hannah')] == 'hannah':
...             d['hannah'] = d.get('hannah',0)+1
... 
>>> d
{'hannah': 4}
>>>
```

This searches the `string` for `hannah` by splicing the string iteratively from index 0 all the way up to the length of the string minus the length of `hannah`

Answer (score 1):

```
'''
s: main string
sub: sub-string
count: number of sub-strings found
p: use the found sub-string's index in p for finding the next occurrence of next sub-string
'''
count=0
p=0
for letter in s:
    p=s.find(sub,p)   
    if(p!=-1):
        count+=1
        p+=1
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count also nonconsecutive substrings, this is the way to do it

```
def subword(lookup,whole):
    if len(whole)<len(lookup):
          return 0
    if lookup==whole:
          return 1
    if lookup=='':
          return 1
    if lookup[0]==whole[0]:
         return subword(lookup[1:],whole[1:])+subword(lookup,whole[1:])
    return subword(lookup,whole[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Count_overlap(string, substring):   
    count = 0
    start = 0
 
    while start < len(string):
        pos = string.find(substring, start)
  
        if pos != -1:
            start = pos + 1
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    return count
string = "hannahannahskdjhannahannah"
print(Count_overlap(string, "hannah"))
```

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed explanation for your code and how this resolves the question being asked?

Answer (score -2):

Don't want to answer this for you as it's simple enough to work out yourself.

But if I were you I'd use the string.find() method which takes the string you're looking for and the position to start looking from, combined with a while loop which uses the result of the find method as it's condition in some way.

That should in theory give you the answer.

Comment: Either give a complete answer, or make a comment.

Comment: Agreed Ricky, not helpful at all.

Comment: I'll make a comment next time but still don't think it's a good idea to write someones code for them, otherwise no one would learn anything. That said the accepted answer was literally an implementation of what I said.

Comment: Yeah because Stackoverflow isn't a teaching resource, it's a Q&A. Sometimes a man just needs a fish, and has no desire to get up to their waist in water trying to figure out how a fishing pole works.